# Array bidimensional con elementos punteros c++

Tags: c++, array, lista

Hola tengo que hacer un array de este tipo arr[32][64] donde cada elemento sea un puntero.

Necesito hacer una matriz de 32x64. Cada elemento de esa matriz es un puntero a una lista enlazada.

No sé cómo declararlo.

Comment: Si un array unidimensional de punteros a `int *`  es `int *puntero[5]`, un array bidimensional es...

Answer (score 1):

Para asignar una matriz o array dimensional a un puntero del mismo tipo puedes usar doble ciclo y lograr la asignación.

```
int *puntero[32][64]; //matriz de punteros 
int a[32][64]; //matriz.
```

Ahora veremos que una matriz de punteros puede contener un array bidimensional. Continuando lo anterior:

```
int i; 
int j;
for (i=0;i<32;i++){ 

for (j=0;j<64;j++){
puntero[i][j]=&a[i][j]; //Asignamos los valores al puntero. 
}

}
```

Como vimos de esta forma guardamos por así decirlo un array bidimensional en un puntero.

Nota: *Es posible guardarlo en un puntero de array de una dimensión si asignamos cada fila una posición del array*.

Comment: A ver si puedes ayudarme, tengo que hacer exactamente esto:
http://oi64.tinypic.com/2zfnwxg.jpg
Cuál sería la mejor solución? Es una matriz de 32x64 donde cada elemento es un puntero a una lista. Es un trabajo de la universidad.

Comment: `Ya que no es posible crear punteros matrices es decir arrays bidimensionales de punteros.` Ehhh... Incorrecto.

Comment: @SJuan76 https://es.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programación_en_C/Punteros

Comment: De aquí lo saqué en la sección matrices de punteros me dio a entender eso. Corrígeme si me equivoco por favor.

Comment: https://ideone.com/2x8mk7

Comment: Uff ya veo. ¿Elimino la respuesta o tiene salvación editandola?

Comment: Si la ves salvable sálvala...

Comment: @SJuan76 ......

Comment: Falta un `&`; no puedes asignar un `int`  a un `int *`

Comment: En cuanto al enlace, yo lo interpreto lo que dice como que un `int *` puede ser equivalente a `int[]` (`a[5]` es equivalente a `a++` 5 veces). Pero si lo haces equivalente a `int[][]` no puede funcionar, ya que al no saber las dimensiones no puede calcular la posición (no puedes calcular `a[5][2]` porque eso depende del tamaño de las "filas").